# Google maps shows empty

Tags: android, google-maps

I want use **`GoogleMap`** in my application, but when running the application on **many** devices it not shows an empty page instead of a Map.

Such as this image:
[image].

**MainActivity codes:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RoutingListener, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks {
    protected GoogleMap map;
    protected LatLng start;
    protected LatLng end;
    @InjectView(R.id.start)
    AutoCompleteTextView starting;
    @InjectView(R.id.destination)
    AutoCompleteTextView destination;
    @InjectView(R.id.send)
    ImageView send;
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "MyActivity";
    protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private PlaceAutoCompleteAdapter mAdapter;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private List<Polyline> polylines;
    private static final int[] COLORS = new int[]{R.color.primary_dark,R.color.primary,R.color.primary_light,
            R.color.accent, R.color.primary_dark_material_light};


    private static final LatLngBounds BOUNDS_JAMAICA= new LatLngBounds(new LatLng(-57.965341647205726, 144.9987719580531),
            new LatLng(72.77492067739843, -9.998857788741589));

    /**
     * This activity loads a map and then displays the route and pushpins on it.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.inject(this);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        polylines = new ArrayList<>();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
        MapsInitializer.initialize(this);
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        if (mapFragment == null) {
            mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map, mapFragment).commit();
        }
        map = mapFragment.getMap();

        mAdapter = new PlaceAutoCompleteAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                mGoogleApiClient, BOUNDS_JAMAICA, null);


        /*
        * Updates the bounds being used by the auto complete adapter based on the position of the
        * map.
        * */
        map.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition position) {
                LatLngBounds bounds = map.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;
                mAdapter.setBounds(bounds);
            }
        });


        CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(18.013610, -77.498803));
        CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(16);

        map.moveCamera(center);
        map.animateCamera(zoom);

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5000, 0,
                new LocationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                        CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude()));
                        CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(16);

                        map.moveCamera(center);
                        map.animateCamera(zoom);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

                    }
                });


        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                3000, 0, new LocationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                        CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude()));
                        CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(16);

                        map.moveCamera(center);
                        map.animateCamera(zoom);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

                    }
                });

        /*
        * Adds auto complete adapter to both auto complete
        * text views.
        * */
        starting.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        destination.setAdapter(mAdapter);


        /*
        * Sets the start and destination points based on the values selected
        * from the autocomplete text views.
        * */

        starting.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                final PlaceAutoCompleteAdapter.PlaceAutocomplete item = mAdapter.getItem(position);
                final String placeId = String.valueOf(item.placeId);
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Autocomplete item selected: " + item.description);

            /*
             Issue a request to the Places Geo Data API to retrieve a Place object with additional
              details about the place.
              */
                PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> placeResult = Places.GeoDataApi
                        .getPlaceById(mGoogleApiClient, placeId);
                placeResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(PlaceBuffer places) {
                        if (!places.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                            // Request did not complete successfully
                            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Place query did not complete. Error: " + places.getStatus().toString());
                            places.release();
                            return;
                        }
                        // Get the Place object from the buffer.
                        final Place place = places.get(0);

                        start=place.getLatLng();
                    }
                });

            }
        });
        destination.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                final PlaceAutoCompleteAdapter.PlaceAutocomplete item = mAdapter.getItem(position);
                final String placeId = String.valueOf(item.placeId);
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Autocomplete item selected: " + item.description);

            /*
             Issue a request to the Places Geo Data API to retrieve a Place object with additional
              details about the place.
              */
                PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> placeResult = Places.GeoDataApi
                        .getPlaceById(mGoogleApiClient, placeId);
                placeResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(PlaceBuffer places) {
                        if (!places.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                            // Request did not complete successfully
                            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Place query did not complete. Error: " + places.getStatus().toString());
                            places.release();
                            return;
                        }
                        // Get the Place object from the buffer.
                        final Place place = places.get(0);

                        end=place.getLatLng();
                    }
                });

            }
        });

        /*
        These text watchers set the start and end points to null because once there's
        * a change after a value has been selected from the dropdown
        * then the value has to reselected from dropdown to get
        * the correct location.
        * */
        starting.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int startNum, int before, int count) {
                if (start != null) {
                    start = null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

        destination.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {


                if(end!=null)
                {
                    end=null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

    }

    @OnClick(R.id.send)
    public void sendRequest()
    {
        if(Util.Operations.isOnline(this))
        {
            route();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,"No internet connectivity",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void route()
    {
        if(start==null || end==null)
        {
            if(start==null)
            {
                if(starting.getText().length()>0)
                {
                    starting.setError("Choose location from dropdown.");
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Please choose a starting point.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            if(end==null)
            {
                if(destination.getText().length()>0)
                {
                    destination.setError("Choose location from dropdown.");
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Please choose a destination.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please wait.",
                    "Fetching route information.", true);
            Routing routing = new Routing.Builder()
                    .travelMode(AbstractRouting.TravelMode.DRIVING)
                    .withListener(this)
                    .alternativeRoutes(true)
                    .waypoints(start, end)
                    .build();
            routing.execute();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onRoutingFailure(RouteException e) {
        // The Routing request failed
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        if(e != null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong, Try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRoutingStart() {
        // The Routing Request starts
    }

    @Override
    public void onRoutingSuccess(List<Route> route, int shortestRouteIndex)
    {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(start);
        CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(16);

        map.moveCamera(center);


        if(polylines.size()>0) {
            for (Polyline poly : polylines) {
                poly.remove();
            }
        }

        polylines = new ArrayList<>();
        //add route(s) to the map.
        for (int i = 0; i <route.size(); i++) {

            //In case of more than 5 alternative routes
            int colorIndex = i % COLORS.length;

            PolylineOptions polyOptions = new PolylineOptions();
            polyOptions.color(getResources().getColor(COLORS[colorIndex]));
            polyOptions.width(10 + i * 3);
            polyOptions.addAll(route.get(i).getPoints());
            Polyline polyline = map.addPolyline(polyOptions);
            polylines.add(polyline);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Route "+ (i+1) +": distance - "+ route.get(i).getDistanceValue()+": duration - "+ route.get(i).getDurationValue(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        // Start marker
        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
        options.position(start);
        options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.start_blue));
        map.addMarker(options);

        // End marker
        options = new MarkerOptions();
        options.position(end);
        options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.end_green));
        map.addMarker(options);

    }

    @Override
    public void onRoutingCancelled() {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Routing was cancelled.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

        Log.v(LOG_TAG,connectionResult.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }
}
```

**MainActivity XML :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:elevation="100dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="20dp">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/start"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:hint="Choose a starting point..." />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/dotted" />

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/destination"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:hint="Choose a destination..." />
            </LinearLayout>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/send"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_width="36dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_send_grey600_48dp"
                android:layout_height="36dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</FrameLayout>
```

**Manifest :**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.directions.sample" >
    <!-- Copied from Google Maps Library/AndroidManifest.xml. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <!-- External storage for caching. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <!-- Maps API needs OpenGL ES 2.0. -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyCXb3CVEfeUQiT7-J-KOvKaqWILPVBkIqg"/>
```

For **GeoAPI** i use `Place API` .

How can i fix this problem?

Comment: Have you checked Logcat if there is any Error ?

Comment: you may want to Check for the Google Service being installed or not just before initiating Google Map view

Comment: I think its wrong Api Key on Google Console.. the problem is on release mode only ? On debug mode you show the map?

Comment: @Cliff, i added devices in AndroidStudio and run application on this devices. show map on few devices and not show some of devices! how can i fix it?

Comment: @Palang are you sure for the api key? any error on logcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see in the screenshot you've added, looks like your map fragment loaded already (check the Google logo in the bottom-left corner). Due to slower internet the map is taking long time to load perhaps.

Comment: I wait to 10min, and not load any map!

Comment: or try to change in your manifest :
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"

Comment: I should use `android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"` , because i fetch location names from google

Comment: Jst try to use android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" and check if you get the map. You can use the location API to fetch the location.

Comment: When use maps.v2.API show me this error in log cat : http://uupload.ir/files/dbn4_26.jpg

Comment: the error means .. Google map permission is disabled under your existing key. You should enable "Google Maps Android API " from google developer console under the "Google Maps API"

Comment: And check again your api key

Answer (score 0):

```
 <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyCXb3CVEfeUQiT7-J-KOvKaqWILPVBkIqg"/>
```

try this:

```
 <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyCXb3CVEfeUQiT7-J-KOvKaqWILPVBkIqg"/>
```

> Note: As shown above, com.google.android.geo.API_KEY is the
>   recommended metadata name for the API key. A key with this name can be
>   used to authenticate to multiple Google Maps-based APIs on the Android
>   platform, including the Google Maps Android API. For backwards
>   compatibility, the API also supports the name
>   com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY. This legacy name allows
>   authentication to the Android Maps API v2 only. An application can
>   specify only one of the API key metadata names. If both are specified,
>   the API throws an exception.

Comment: I should use `android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"` , because i fetch location names from google

Comment: For backwards compatibility, the API also supports the name com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY.